# Show $\exists\, k >1 \forall x\in [a,b] f(x)\geq k\, g(x) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions, and suppose that $0<g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x$ element of [a,b]. Prove that

$$\exists\, k >1\quad \forall x\in [a,b]\quad f(x)\geq k\, g(x) $$

Consider the function $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ Then $h(x)$ is
continuous since $f$ and $g$ are, thus by Intermediate Value Theorem  the image set $h(I)$ is also an interval so exists $k >1$ such that $h(x)>k$

Please correct my proof or is there another proof

Update :
since h(x) is continuous on bounded interval $[a,b]$ then h has minimum value $m$ on compact interval $[a,b]$ so 
$$\exists x_{0}\in [a,b]\quad h(x_0)=m $$

and $$\forall x \in [a,b],\quad  h(x)\geq h(x_0) $$

and since $\forall x\in[a,b]\quad h(x)>0$  then $h(x_0)>0$ and $m>0$
thus $$\exists m>0 \forall x\in [a,b] \quad f(x)\geq m\, g(x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $h=f-g$ which is continuous on $[a, b]$ so it has a minimum $\epsilon >0$. As for g, it has a maximum $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$. So, with $k=\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}>0$ you have: $$ \forall x \in  [a,b] \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}f(x)-g(x) \ge \epsilon \\ \frac{g(x)}{\alpha} \in [0,1] \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow f(x)-(1+k)g(x) \begin{array}{ll}\\ \ge f(x) -g(x)-\epsilon \\ \ge 0\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your proof is not correct - although it does have the correct *ideas*.

- You haven't used the fact that $[a, b]$ is a bounded interval; the claim is actually false without this assumption.
- You haven't shown that the interval $h(I)$ isn't something like $(1, a)$, which would actually force $k = 1$.

---

To fix this, you're going to need to use not just the IVT, but the fact that a continuous function attains its maximum / minimum value on a compact interval.

Comment: please check my update

Comment: No, your proof is still not correct. You've concluded a bound $k > 0$ when you wanted $k > 1$.

Comment: could you please write correct one